# Returning IEnumerable<XElement> from WebAPI, error on client-side

Tags: jquery, xml, asp.net-web-api

I have this WebAPI and I'm trying to return xml data to the client.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<XElement> GetPersons(string name)
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
            var result = doc.Element("Persons")
                   .Elements("Person")
                   .Where(x => (string)x.Element("name") == name);

            return result();
        }
```

Invoking data directly (`http://localhost:63068/api/GetPersons/b`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfXElement xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml.Linq" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <XElement>
      <Person xmlns="">
         <PersonID>1</PersonID>
         <Name>b</UserName>         
      </Person>
   </XElement>
   <XElement>
      <Person xmlns="">
         <PersonID>2</PersonID>        
         <Name>b</UserName>
      </Person>
   </XElement>
</ArrayOfXElement>
```

Error when invoking the service from client:

```
$.ajax({
            url: baseURL + 'GetPersons/' + $('#txtUserName2').val(),
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                divResults.html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
                divResults.html(err);
            }
        });

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An item with the same key has already been added.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)\r\n
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it through after making the ajax request - is the format of the `result` as expected? Are you sending the request with correct headers (for xml rather than json)? At what point exactly are you getting the error? I.e. which statement is causing it? Are you working with dictionaries anywhere near this piece of code (or maybe is caching by key involved where key is the name etc)? Is the original xml document well formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your scenario is to have your Web API to return the data that is in the file `path` on the server and your client consume this data.

The issue you are facing here is that `IEnumerable<XElement>` is not serializable into JSON:

```
 The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize 
 the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
```

The reason is that `XElement` is a type that is very XML specific...

Here are 2 implementations to your scenario:

1. Modify your Web API to return in JSON and your client ajax code will work
2. Modify your client ajax code to read from XML

I would prefer #1 because it's easier to read JSON on the client side.  The idea here is to deserialize your data into a CLR type on the server side so that we can take advantage of the content negotiation to serialize the response into JSON.  Here are the steps I would take to implement #1:

- Create a `Persons` class.  One easy way to do this is to copy the content of your XML file onto the clipboard and use the 'Paste XML As Classes' feature in Visual Studio (under Edit > Paste Special)
- Use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the data defined in `path` into the type `Persons` created in the above step:

  ```
      using (var streamReader = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
      {
          var xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Persons));
          results = xmlS.Deserialize(streamReader) as Persons;
      }
  ```
- Do any additional business logic you have (i.e. filter by the name)
- Have your `GetPersons` to return the type `Persons`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you!